# Is there any way to create automatically check boxes in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop, while-loop

My plan is to automatically create checkboxes with names and random values for example a hundred in a for loop. Is there any way to do this?
And if i want to use these how to change the value and save it to the array?

Comment: In `javascript` or `php`? Yes, it is doable in both, you'd just need to code it

Comment: Why is this tagged `mysql`?

Answer (score 1):

in php

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
echo '<input type="checkbox">';
}
//if you want to add a submit btn at last
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
?>
```

It is the code to automatically create 100 checkboxes
And put your own values and styles

Comment: And if i want to use these how to change the value and save it to the array?